# How to enable uvicorn to run asynchronously constructed app?

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, uvicorn, asgi

Given `main.py`:

```
import asyncio

async def new_app():
    # Await some things.

    async def app(scope, receive, send):
        ...

    return app

app = asyncio.run(new_app())
```

followed by:

```
uvicorn main.app
```

gives:

```
RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop
```

This is because `uvicorn` already started an event loop prior to importing my application. How can I asynchronously construct an application under `uvicorn`?

Answer (score 4):

You need not use `asyncio.run`. Your class or function should only implement the [`ASGI`](https://asgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specs/main.html) interface. Like so, simplest workable:

```
# main.py
def app(scope):
    async def asgi(receive, send):
        await send(
            {
                "type": "http.response.start",
                "status": 200,
                "headers": [[b"content-type", b"text/plain"]],
            }
        )
        await send({"type": "http.response.body", "body": b"Hello, world!"})

    return asgi
```

And you can start it under uvicorn: `uvicorn main:app`.

Parameter `main:app` will be parsed imported by `uvicorn` and [executed](https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/blob/a504c56963fb0d4c9add33fe3d1cb3fc25d82fdb/uvicorn/lifespan/on.py) in such manner within its eventloop:

```
 app = self.config.loaded_app
 scope: LifespanScope = {
     "type": "lifespan",
     "asgi": {"version": self.config.asgi_version, "spec_version": "2.0"},
 }
 await app(scope, self.receive, self.send)
```

If you want to make an executable module, you can do this:

```
import uvicorn
# app definition
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Answer (score 0):

With fastapi you can do extra setup in startup event handlers:

```py
def create_app() -> FastAPI:
    app = FastAPI()

    @app.on_event("startup")
    async def metrics_setup():
        pass  # await anything
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @aiven's answer, in blacksheep you also have a startup event:

```
@app.on_start
async def init_db( context: blacksheep.Application ) -> None:
    pass # await anything
```